# IIS site worked before adding an IIS role, now after removing role site no longer works

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016, asp.net

I have an ASP net application running through IIS which was working fine - I could call the API using Postman and get 200 response codes. After I added a role through Server Manager (URL Authorization) to troubleshoot an authorization issue and then removed the role, I no longer receive 200 response codes via Postman. I have everything configured back to how it was before adding the role yet Postman gives me a 500 status code and I have also verified this using curl.

Is there something else I'm not aware of that URL Authorization changed when I added it?

update:
turns out it was URL authorization that I needed, I must have messed up my initial declaration of the ACL

Answer (score 0):

Open IIS Manager and click on your site, then double-click Authorization. Anonymous Authentication should be Enabled and everything else Disabled.

Comment: I have it set back to Basic auth which is what it was set to before when it was working.

Comment: @Kevys so is it working now?

Comment: No it continues to not work. I have even created a new site with exact settings as before but new path and even that does not work. I think there is some overall IIS configuration that was changed when I added URL Authorization that I'm not aware of, perhaps the app pool

Comment: @Kevys there is also an Authorization widget at the machine level in IIS. Click on the server name.

Comment: At the server level in authorization it's set to allow all users and authentication is set to anonymous authentication